# Minecraft 13w47e Server Disregards Files

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server

Recently, I updated my Minecraft server to snapshot 13w47e. It started up without any trouble; however, upon logging in, I find myself in a new world without any of my previous items.

Upon further scrutiny, I find that the server is completely ignoring the files in the folder that it's in. The world is never loaded, no log files are saved, nothing. Not only that, but it never actually generates a world and can run independently in its own empty folder, without creating any files.

Can someone please tell me what is going on? Thanks for any help. I feel I am pretty good with Minecraft servers, but this is beyond strange.

---TECHNICAL DETAILS---

My operating system is Ubuntu 13.04 and I am using the OpenJDK JRE, if that helps at all.

Here is the output of `ls -la`:

```
total 8992
drwx------ 4 dillon dillon    4096 Nov 23 08:42 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 dillon dillon    4096 Nov 21 09:01 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dillon dillon     108 Nov 17 13:02 banned-ips.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dillon dillon     186 Nov 17 15:07 banned-players.txt
drwx------ 2 dillon dillon    4096 Nov 18 07:00 logs
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dillon dillon      71 Nov 17 13:02 ops.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dillon dillon 9167277 Nov 23 08:42 server.jar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dillon dillon     636 Nov 17 13:02 server.properties
-rw-rw-r-- 1 dillon dillon       0 Nov  6 17:39 white-list.txt
drwx------ 8 dillon dillon    4096 Nov 23 08:42 world
```

and here is the output from `ps uax | grep mine`:

```
dillon    4580  0.0  0.0  20428   944 pts/1    S+   15:48   0:00 grep --color=auto mine
```

This is what I see when I start the server up.

```
[16:03:33] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting minecraft server version 13w47e
[16:03:33] [Server thread/INFO]: Loading properties
[16:03:33] [Server thread/INFO]: Default game type: SURVIVAL
[16:03:33] [Server thread/INFO]: Generating keypair
[16:03:34] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting Minecraft server on *:25565
[16:03:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing level "world"
[16:03:35] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing start region for level 0
[16:03:36] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 0%
[16:03:37] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 27%
[16:03:38] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 65%
[16:03:39] [Server thread/INFO]: Done (4.630s)! For help, type "help" or "?"
```

This startup seems to be much shorter than usual. This is strange because 13w47e added no performance tweaks, so it's hard to tell what's going on.

Comment: Was that output with minecraft running? what user do minecraft runs?

Comment: There should only be two users on my computer. One is `dillon` and the other would be `root`.

Comment: Actually there are about 15, but that's not important. How you run Minecraft normally? Dobleclick? Command line? Start as service? as root?

Comment: Here's the command I use: `java -Xms2G -Xmx2G -jar server.jar nogui`.

Comment: No errors get printed in the command line?

Comment: None. That's the strange part. I'll edit with a sample startup in the Terminal emulator.

Comment: How are you trying to run it?  It's possible it's using a different folder.